# Javascript getting specific data from object by name or id

Tags: javascript

I have this data:

```
var data = [
  {
    id=1,
    text="text1"
  },
  {
    id=2,
    text="text2"
  }
];
```

And I'm trying to get a specific value by either name or id.

So I've tried this:

```
Object.values(obj.text='text2');
```

or

```
Object.values(obj[0].text);
```

But none work.

How do I do this without needing a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nidhin pointed out, you need to correct your JSON first. replace `=` sign with `:`

```
[
  {
    id:1,
    text:"text1"
  },
  {
    id:2,
    text:"text2"
  }
];
```

Then try

```
data[0].id     //expected output is 1
data[0].text   //expected output is text1
```

Similarly

```
data[1].id     //expected output is 2
data[1].text   //expected output is text2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to get data by id or name

```
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "text1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "text2"
  }
];

console.log(data.find(e => (e.text === 'text1' || e.id == 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first have a proper JSON structure. Once that, you can use the [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the required output.

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "text1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "text2"
  }
];

console.log(data.filter(e => e.text === 'text1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to format the objects in the `data` array properly, by replacing `=` with `:`.

You can then iterate the data array with `forEach` and single-out any object in it by a criteria of your choice. For example, get the text of the object with id 1:

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "text1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "text2"
  }
];

data.forEach(function(obj) {
  // if object id equals 1, get its text
  if(obj.id == 1){
    console.log(obj.text);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is not a valid `JSON` . Put `:` instead of `=` . Now as you are going to find element by `id` or `text` put using OR condition.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "text":"text1"
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "text":"text2"
  }
];

console.log(data.find(x => x['id'] === 1 || x['text'] === "text1" ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this: `data[0].id`

Example:

```
console.log(data[0].id);
```

*Explanation*: `data[0]` selects an item in the array, then `.id` accesses the id property.

To iterate through all items then try this:

```
data.forEach((item) => {
   console.log(item.id)
})
```